# Excluding directories using wildcards

Tags: windows, wildcard, xcopy

I using `xcopy`, and I am trying to exclude directories with specific ending name from copying.
I've put the bellow line in exclude_files.txt to ignore those directories:

```
\\\*_bkup\\
```

Also, the xcopy command is the one bellow:

```
xcopy "C:\localfolder" "\\\server\remotefolder" /E /exclude:exclusion_list.txt
```

Only that it just doesn't ignore those directories. 
What would the workaround be? I need it to ignore these directories in all of the tree's structure, not only in the root.

Comment: `xcopy` is kind of lame. With `xcopy`, you can't even recursively copy a directory. You should probably follow benham's advice and use `robocopy`.

Answer (score 3):

The `/EXCLUDE` option does not use wild cards in the masks. Use `_bkup\` instead, without the wildcard.

But really you should be using ROBOCOPY instead. It may take a bit more study to figure it out, but it is much more powerful and precise.